# Slicing/reshaping numpy array challenge

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I have a Numpy array of thousands of values like:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and I'd like to reshape the array to be able to vectorize a calculation on segments of the array of fixed-width like this:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 ...]
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Here are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485669/consecutive-overlapping-subsets-of-array-numpy-python (I'd go with `as_strided`, personally).

Comment: That is perfect, thanks so much @ajcr!