# how to split a list into a nested list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split a list into a nest list. The list I have is this:

```
[1,2,1,3,2]
```

Now, I want the output to be like this:

```
[[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,2]]
```

Is there any possible of doing the output as mentioned above?

Comment: You are looking for all combination (2 items) of inputs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [bi-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). Here is a generic function to generate n-grams from a sequence.

```
def ngrams(seq, n):
    return [seq[i:i + n] for i in range(len(seq) - n + 1)]

a = [1,2,1,3,2]

print ngrams(a, 2)

# [[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: python3 does not have `xrange` generator

Comment: Excellent sliding window!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `zip`

```
lst = [1,2,1,3,2]

res = [list(pair) for pair in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
print(res)  # -> [[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 2]]
```

**Note**: the first instance of `lst` in `zip` does not have to be sliced since it is the smallest of the two that dictates the number of tuples that will be generated.

---

As @Jean-FrancoisFabre said in the comments, if the original list is *big*, you might want to go with a generator instead of a *hard* slice.

```
res = [list(pair) for pair in zip(lst, itertools.islice(lst, 1, None))]
```

The benefit of this approach (or the drawback of the previous one) is that the second list used in `zip` (`lst[1:]`) is not created in memory, but you will need to `import itertools` for it to work.

Comment: you can avoid a hard slice with `itertools.islice(lst,1,None)` for second arg.

Comment: `[list(pair) for pair in zip(lst, itertools.islice(lst,1,None))]`: no extra list creation

Comment: I am not totally convinced by `islice` benefits here.. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485777/9209546

Comment: I would assume that there exists a list-length `n` above which the `itertools.islice` performs better. Might run some checks later to figure out what `n` is. Thanks for the link!